# Надо обрезать до определенной точки

Tags: java, текст, substring

есть текст hh.sds.ds.rr, нужно его обрезать от . до rr, получится .rr, но когда я делаю через indexOf, то он находит самую первую точку и все .sds, а мне нужно чтобы он самую последнюю брал, как это сделать? И да, текст все время изменяется, поэтому нужно , чтобы он искал самую последнюю точку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `lastIndexOf(char)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "hh.sds.ds.rr";
    String result = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.'));
    System.out.println(result); // ".rr"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще насколько я знаю у метода `subString` нужно указать начальный индекс и конечный. То есть типа такого:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

стартовым индексом будет индекс точки, а конечным будет последний индекс точки `lastIndexOf(String str)`. То есть вы будете обрезать до точки перед буквой `r`. Не уверен что совсем идеальное решение, но должно делать то что вам нужно. [Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String))